# Removing users from my service

Tags: vline

Say, for development purposes, I created too many vline users, i.e. in a loop.

Is there a way to remove/delete them completely from my service? Also, is there a limit on the number of users created?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently delete users in our system, but you can delete them or prevent them from logging in to your system through whatever user account system you are using. There is currently no limit on the number of users created.